# I failed making a VM from image. I got this error

Tags: linux, azure, virtual-machine, provisioning

I made a VM for making a Image in Azure.
After I made the linux vm(Redhat), I stop the vm and made image.
But I failed making the vm from image.

Both cases have the same problems
 -1st case:I didn't install anything.
 -2nd case:I install something and made ssh key(rsa)

If i execute this command 'sudo waagent -deprovision+user', there is no error.
BUT my ssh key disappear so my VMs from image cannot connect each other, which means that I cannot generate a cluster by using Ambari.

Is there any way to solve this problem?

this is error I got when I failed making a VM from image.

> --------error---- Provisioning failed. OS Provisioning for VM 'master0' did not finish in the
>   allotted time. However, the VM guest agent was detected running. This
>   suggests the guest OS has not been properly prepared to be used as a
>   VM image (with CreateOption=FromImage). To resolve this issue, either
>   use the VHD as is with CreateOption=Attach or prepare it properly for
>   use as an image: * Instructions for Windows:
>   https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-upload-image/
>   * Instructions for Linux: https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-capture-image/.
>   OSProvisioningTimedOut

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you create a image, you should execute `sudo waagent -deprovision+user`. If you don't do it, you will get this error.

According to your scenario, you could configure `Provisioning.RegenerateSshHostKeyPair=n` (/etc/waagent.conf). According this [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-linux-agent-user-guide?toc=%2fazure%2fvirtual-machines%2flinux%2ftoc.json#command-line-options)

> deprovision: Attempt to clean the system and make it suitable for
>   re-provisioning. This operation deleted the following:
>
> All SSH host keys (if Provisioning.RegenerateSshHostKeyPair is 'y' in
>   the configuration file)

If it does not work for you, I suggest you could add `publickey` to your VMs by using Azure Portal.

[image]